# THree.js collada loader

Tags: three.js, webgl, loader, collada

It is interesting that all examples using `Collada loader` loads have  one model. I am having trouble loading multiple.  I have tried the following

1) Create one loader and just try to load all models using it without waiting for previous
   one to finish.  This failed it looked like i got mixture of models in my models

2) Create one loader and wait for each model to load before loading next.  This failed
   but I am not sure if I am doing something wrong.

3) Create a different Loader for each model.  This works but it seems a waster.

My question is how is three.js Collada Loader designed to handle multiple models?

Comment: The Collada loader may not be the right choice for loading full scenes. I recommend that you have a look at the scene JSON format used by three.js. You can explore a working example under the editor (click the export button to see the JSON output) http://threejs.org/editor/

Comment: You can generate the JSON from FBX Scenes using tools such as this: https://github.com/zfedoran/convert-to-threejs-json